# Aurelia multi project build with Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia and the new aurelia-webpack-plugin (2.0.0-rc.2). I want to use this as a "multiproject build":

```
.
├── project1
├── project2
├── project3
├── build
```

The three projects are all using Aurelia (same versions), but are independent. To avoid build script duplicates I extracted the webpack.config.js and several other scripts to the build folder. The projects are calling them via npm scripts from the package.json of the project. The working directory of this node-process is changed to the build folder before webpack is called.

Some relevant configs in my webpack config:

```
...
new AureliaPlugin({
    includeAll: path.resolve(`${projectDir}/app/`),
    viewsFor: `${path.resolve(projectDir)}/app/**/*.{ts,js}`
})
...
entry: {
    main: "aurelia-bootstrapper"
},
resolve: {
    modules: [`${projectDir}/app`, `${projectDir}/node_modules`, "node_modules"]
}
...
```

projectDir points to the specific root directory of the project.

The problem is now, that the `GlobDependenciesPlugin` inside the aurelia-webpack-plugin does not find the entrypoints (Main.ts) of the projects.

After debugging I found at least two reasons for this:

- this.root in GlobDependenciesPlugin points to the current cwd of the node process, which is the build folder (there is no way to configure the value)
- only the last "node_modules" folder in the modules array from the config is used for searching. The others are filtered out, cause of relative paths.

Is there a way to get this working with this shared build script structure?

Comment: Solution described here: https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/115